# Unable to alter CSS styles by id

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a very simple div in my footer:

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import style from "./DesktopFooter.module.css";

const DesktopFooter = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <div className={style.container}>
      <div className={style.footerNav} id="phoneNumber">
        999-999-9999
      </div>
      <div className={style.footerNav}>

      </div>
      <div className={style.footerNav}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DesktopFooter;
```

In my CSS I want to style both on the class and id:

```
.footerNav {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

#phoneNumber {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

However my component is not recognizing the id styling I try to apply.

Could anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure you style file is loaded?

Comment: yes the class styles work fine

Comment: Can we get the code as running snippet? Have you tried style.phoneNumber?

Answer (score 0):

Ya, After you update a question, I found the issue, you are try to load style for id as normal Dom, but its will not work since you are not include css file as is, you are import style file to style param...

so, what you need to do is replace `id="PhoneNumber"` to this

```
<div className={styles["footerNav"]} id={styles["phoneNumber"]}>
        999-999-9999
      </div>
```

Check the [demo url](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-thunder-p8gmo?file=/src/App.js)

Full Code:

```
import React from "react";
import style from "./MyComponent.module.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className={style.container}>
      <div className={style["footerNav"]} id={style["phoneNumber"]}>
        999-999-9999
      </div>
      <div className={style.footerNav}></div>
      <div className={style.footerNav}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok I will give this a try.  I have no issue with the className styles though. `className={styles.footerNav} works totally fine.

Comment: Nice, test it, and let me know about the result

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having it as either a class or an id. Classes usually have a higher priority, meaning that the id will be ignored.
This is what it should look like:

```
    .phoneNumber {
     font-size: 2rem;
     width: 50%;
     display: flex;
     }
```

```
    <div class = "phoneNumber">999-999-9999</div>
```

However, if you would like to get around this, I would use another element within the div, such as:

```
    #myID{
    font-size: 2rem;
    }
    .phoneNumber {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    }
```

```
    <div class = "phoneNumber">
    <p id="myID"> 999-999-999 </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution, or at least a work around.  The problem seems to be that the file was a css module and not just a css file.

I changed the name of the css file from DesktopFooter.module.css to DesktopFooter.css

and I changed my import statement from

import style from "./DesktopFooter.module.css" to import "./DesktopFooter.css

Comment: This is the normal flow of css!, so its not a correct answer to resolve your issue if your project work base on module
but if you didnt have a rule to use module or not, then its will work and its one of common use...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Everything works if you get rid of the module.

Comment: To import style in react there is many of ways, for example, module if style suffix with module, or normal style if fileName.styleExt, or via css in js and so on...
Now, if your project set a rules to use module, then you need to follow module rule, and if its normal style then you need to follow it and so on...for example in current comapny we are use normal style import like ./fileName.scss and in prev one we use css in js like styled-component, so that, when we answer your question we answer it to be work as a module import, since your style contain .module...

Comment: So that the correct answer base on question by follow the module rule...but if you dont care about which way need to use style ... then when remove module will fix issue and thats correct, since you change style flow from module to normal style import...(I like to use that by the way or css in js)...good luck